(this/thought/action/action input/observation can repeat N times) - agent entering infinite loop after giving the answer in terminal
i am doing langchain CSV agent with streamlit ,
it is working well upon upload of csv file and when question asked , it gives answer while entering agentexecutor chain ..
i can see the answer in "observation" but then it continues to loop giving (this/thought/action/action input/observation can repeat N times) , for some iterations and ends up with "Agent stopped due to iteration limit or time limit"
import streamlit as st
import tempfile
from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits.pandas.base import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

def main():
    # Configure Streamlit page
    st.set_page_config(page_title="Welcome to CSV ChatBot")
    st.header("Welcome to CSV ChatBot")

    # Allow the user to upload a CSV file
    file = st.file_uploader("upload file", type="csv")

    if file is not None:
        # Create a temporary file to store the uploaded CSV data
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', suffix=".csv", delete=False) as f:
            # Convert bytes to a string before writing to the file
            data_str = file.getvalue().decode('utf-8')
            f.write(data_str)
            f.flush()

            # Create an instance of the OpenAI language model with temperature set to 0
            llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)

            # Ask the user to input a question
            user_input = st.text_input("Question here:")

            # Create a CSV agent using the OpenAI language model and the temporary file
            agent = create_csv_agent(
                llm, f.name, 
                verbose=True,
                handle_parsing_errors=True,  # Handle parsing errors gracefully
                max_iterations=10,  # Set a reasonable number of max iterations
                max_execution_time=60,  # Set a reasonable max execution time in seconds
                early_stopping_method="generate"  # Generate a final response before stopping
            )

            if user_input:
                # Run the agent on the user's question and get the response
                response = agent.run(user_input)
                st.write(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Did you by any chance solve this?
